# How to use template arguments for a template class outside of it?

Tags: c++, templates, matrix, operator-overloading, matrix-multiplication

*This is a beginner question:*

How to use template arguments for a function that works with a template class outside of it?

This is my matrix class that uses a template.

```
template<typename T, int N, int M>
class matrix {
    T vals[N][M] = {};

public:
    matrix() {
        //sth
    }
};
```

Now I want to write an operation (muliplication) for it **outside of** the class.
How does that work with the template parameters?

```
matrix<?????????> operator*(matrix<<?????????>& m1, matrix<?????????>& m2) {
    //multiply code
}
```

What do I need to write where the question marks are written?
The same? `typename T, int N, int M`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well... if you want the classic matrix multiplication... so if given a D1xD2 matrix multiplied for a D2xD3 matrix you want a D1xD3 matrix...

```
template <typename T, std::size_t D1, std::size_t D2, std::size_t D3>
matrix<T, D1, D3> operator* (matrix<T, D1, D2> const & m1,
                             matrix<T, D2, D3> const & m2)
 {
   // ....
 }
```

Off Topic: I suggest (as you can see in my example) the use of an unsigned value (maybe `std::size_t`) for dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

```
template<typename T, int N, int M>
class matrix {
    T vals[N][M] = {};

public:
    matrix() {
        //sth
    }
};

template <typename T, int N, int M>
matrix<T, N, M> operator*(matrix<T, N, M> l, matrix<T, N, M> r) {
    return matrix<T, N, M>{};
}
```

live: https://godbolt.org/z/5dJOXK

You can also write it as a friend and not have to re-type out all the template stuff:

```
template<typename T, int N, int M>
class matrix {
    T vals[N][M] = {};

public:
    matrix() {
        //sth
    }

    friend matrix<T, N, M> operator*(matrix<T, N, M> l, matrix<T, N, M> r) {
        return matrix<T, N, M>};
    }
};
```

or just as a member:

```
template<typename T, int N, int M>
class matrix {
    T vals[N][M] = {};

public:
    matrix() {
        //sth
    }

    matrix<T, N, M> operator*(matrix<T, N, M> r) {
        return matrix<T, N, M>{};
    }
};
```

Comment: If I may offer a couple improvements; OP wanted to return a `matrix`, not `T`, and matrix multiplication takes an NxM matrix and a MxP matrix to produce a NxP matrix

Comment: You're totally right - and while it doesn't materially change the answer (regarding syntax), I'll fix it right up :)

Comment: That doesn't make much sense for matrix multiplication unless N and M are the same.

Comment: Well, regardless -- the core question is what is the syntax for the template... what business logic makes sense here is really just a red herring.